Initial topology and base
I consider a family $(f_i, Y_i)_{i\in I}$ where each $Y_i$ is a topological space and each $f_i$ a map from $X$ to $Y_i$. The initial topology on $X$ is the topology generated by $\{f_{i}^{-1}(U_i) : i\in I, U_i\in\mathcal{O}_{Y_i}\}$.
I would like to show that if for each $i\in I$, $\mathcal{B}_i$ is a base for the topology $\mathcal{O}_{Y_i}$, then the set of finite intersections of elements of $\{f_{i}^{-1}(U_i) : i\in I, U_i\in\mathcal{B}_i\}$ is a base for the initial topology of $X$.
I think it is something basic we obtain applying the definition but I did not manage to conclude. Indeed, take $O$ an open set of $X$ for the initial topology, this means $O=\bigcup_{j\in J}A_j$ where $A_j =\bigcap_{i=1}^{N_j}f_{i}^{-1}(U_i)$ (where $N_j\in\mathbb{N}$), now for each $U_i$ we have $U_i = \bigcup_{k\in K_i}B_{k}^{i}$ with each $B_{k}^{i}\in\mathcal{B}_i$. This gives
$$
O = \bigcup_{j\in J}\bigcap_{i=1}^{N_j}f_{i}^{-1}(\bigcup_{k\in K_i}B_{k}^{i})=\bigcup_{j\in J}\bigcap_{i=1}^{N_j}\bigcup_{k\in K_i}f_{i}^{-1}(B_{k}^{i})
$$
And I do not see how proceed once here. Have you any hint to provide please ?
Thank you a lot

$\mathcal S = \{f_{i}^{-1}(U_i) : i\in I, U_i\in\mathcal{O}_{Y_i}\}$ is a subbase for the initial topology. Hence the set $\mathcal B$ of all finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal S$ is a base.
Let $U$ be open in $X$ and $x \in U$. There exists $\bigcap_{k=1}^n f_{i_k}^{-1}(U_{i_k}) \in \mathcal B$ such that $x \in \bigcap_{k=1}^n f_{i_k}^{-1}(U_{i_k}) \subset U$. Then $f_{i_k}(x) \in U_{i_k}$. There exist $V_{i_k} \in  \mathcal{B}_{i_k}$ such that $f_{i_k}(x) \in V_{i_k} \subset U_{i_k}$. This implies $x \in  \bigcap_{k=1}^n f_{i_k}^{-1}(V_{i_k}) \subset  \bigcap_{k=1}^n f_{i_k}^{-1}(U_{i_k}) \subset U$. This proves your claim.
